# How to check dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[image: E-R diagram]

I need advice.
I want to write a trigger that will populate the `Id_tariff` in the `Elec_prod` table.
`Date_measurement` is SYSDATE.
Depending on when the table entry is made, I want SQL to enter the appropriate `Id_tariff`.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

I'm thinking about writing a COMPOUND trigger to first download the entire contents of the e_tariffs table and then compare date_measurement with Date_start in a loop

Comment: A [database] trigger is executed after an INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE has been performed. What [database] table(s) should cause the trigger to execute?

Comment: I want an entry to the id_tariff column to be made in the Elec_prod table after an insert or update

Comment: "Depending on when the table entry is made, I want SQL to enter the appropriate `Id_tariff`." What would be the logic for an "appropriate" `id_tariff`? Please [edit] your question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables (as text, not images); **YOUR** attempt at a solution to the problem, the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; a complete English, not code, description of the logic that you want to implement; and details of the expected output for a sample insert or update statement.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the [Oracle PL/SQL language reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#LNPLS-GUID-E76C8044-6942-4573-B7DB-3502FB96CF6F), you want something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EProd_Tariff_Add
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF Date_measurement ON Elec_Prod
DECLARE
   Found_Tariff NUMBER(3)
BEGIN
   -- look up matching tariff
   SELECT ID_Tariff FROM E_tariffs
   INTO Found_Tariff 
   WHERE :NEW.Date_Measurement>=E_tariffs.Date_start
   FETCH FIRST 1  ROWS

   -- apply update
   UPDATE Elec_Prod Set ID_Tariff = Found_Tariff
END
```

Comment: this looks ok 
thanks

Comment: You need to add `FOR EACH ROW`, not least so you can reference the `:NEW` pseudorow. Your `SELECT` needs an `ORDER BY` clause or you'll fetch one indeterminate matching row. Don't `UPDATE` - that would (if it worked) update the entire table; set the value for this row instead, with `:NEW.ID_Tariff := Found_Tariff;`. You're also missing a few semicolons. (And this will error if there are no tariffs available, but the OP hasn't said if that can happen or what to do if it does.)